# datalayer variable isn't working - custom HTML code on GTM

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

Apologies for my lack of web-dev lingo. I'm a digital marketer and our web developer has recently left the team, so I have been stuck on what I believe should be a relatively easy task for **weeks**:

I am trying to install a conversion tracking code and sitewide script for our e-commerce website through GTM, the sitewide script is firing but the variables within the data layer are not working.

My problem is that:

1. The order of the Scripts is switched.  The Avantmetrics array should run before the avmws sitewide script.
2. The Array is populated with variable names instead of values. (i.e. the order id is "id" where it should be the unique ID 4358)

The general tracking script template followed by the site-wide script template is as follows:

```
<!-- AvantLink Order Confirmation script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _AvantMetrics = _AvantMetrics || [];
_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:'[ORDER_ID]', amount:'[ORDER_AMOUNT]', state:'[BILLING_STATE]', country:'[BILLING_COUNTRY]' }]);
_AvantMetrics.push(['item',{ order_id:'[ORDER_ID]', parent_sku:'[ITEM_PARENT_SKU]', variant_sku:'[ITEM_VARIANT_SKU]', price:'[ITEM_PRICE]', qty:'[ITEM_QUANTITY]' }]);
</script>
<!-- AvantLink Sitewide script —>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var avm = document.createElement('script'); avm.type = 'text/javascript'; avm.async = true;
avm.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.avmws.com/1020701/';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(avm, s);
})();
</script>
```

the items in [SQUARE_BRACKET] syntax should be replaced with the variables, which are specific to our eCommerce platform, which uses an Google's enhanced ecommerce data layer.

I have installed the order tracking script onto our thank_you page as follows:

[order tracking script current set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUNIT.png)

I have installed the sitewide script as follows:

[sitewide script current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUXld.png)

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong? I would massively appreciate any help!

Thanks, Harry

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would ensure that the sitewide script fires first.

1. On the order tracking script tag, expand "Advanced Settings."
2. Under "Tag firing options" choose "once per page" from the dropdown.
3. Expand "Tag Sequencing."
4. Check "Fire a tag before this tag fires"
5. Choose your sitewide script tag from the "Setup Tag" dropdown.

As for the variables in your order tracking tag, they are currently set up like this: order_id: 'id', which is like saying "send a string of 'id' as the value for order_id."  If the actual values are indeed available in your dataLayer, add custom variables in GTM for each value. These will be the variable type "Data Layer Variable," and for the "Data Layer Variable Name" field, you input the key that contains the value you want.

For example, if your dataLayer looks like this on your order confirmation page:

```
{
  order_id: "1234",
  revenue: 125,
  ...
}
```

Then you would put order_id as the data layer variable name.

Once you have these variables configured in GTM, you can use them in your order tracking script. GTM uses a double bracket notation to indicate the use of a variable. Let's say you named your data layer variables "order_id" and "revenue":

_AvantMetrics.push(['order',{ order_id:{{order_id}}, amount:{{revenue}} }]);